# How to create rectangular cut slots in PCB footprint?

Tags: altium

Here is mechanical drawing page from datasheet of the PJ-037BH DC Power Jack.

[image]

The drawing shows that there must be rectangular cuts into the PCB for this component to be fitted and soldered. This leads to two questions.

1. What is the correct method to create the through hole pad shape required by this part in Altium designer?
2. What am I supposed to do with the "cut away area 0.5 deep"?

I found a way to change the pad to slot and specify its length under properties. However, that only changes the hole shape and the rest of the pad shape remains circle as can be seen here:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top section of the properties box refers to the pad's X/Y dimensions, and the bottom part refers to the hole. Simply increase your pad's X length to what you desire.

For example:

[image]
[image]

Regarding the "cut away area 0.5 deep", it looks likes a statement, rather than an instruction. Looking at their 3D model, you can see a recessed area under the central pin.

https://www.cuidevices.com/product/resource/3dmodel/pj-037bh
[image]

Comment: Compared with the hole size, what do you think should be the pad size since the pad that will form the solder fillet needs to be larger than the drill hole.

Comment: No need to guess, footprint is available to download (no sign up) from here:
https://www.cuidevices.com/product/resource/pcbfootprint/pj-037bh

Comment: oh, a new website. wow.

Comment: By the way, isn't it basically impossible to cut sharp corner rectangle during manufacture, round rectangle needs to be used instead?

Comment: Presumably you're referring to an internal angle? I can't say if it's impossible but I would say highly impractical - I've only ever had PCBs routed, typically with a 1 or 2mm diameter bit, and as such, give all internal angles a radius

Comment: The datasheet gives rectangluar holes to be drilled. The footprint you have referred to me on the external website also shows rectangle holes being drilled. However, from what I know, this is not possible in PCB manufacture. What am I missing?

Comment: I expect the person who made the footprint is simply inexperienced! I would not attempt a rectangular slot - I would simply use the aforementioned rounded rectangular method. It will be fine, I promise :)

Comment: I have done that in my foot print

Answer (score 0):

For small pins, a hole works just fine. 3mm wide is borderline but 1mm is pretty thick so I would just use a hole.

Larger pins will require special notes and exports to the fab, even if you have it in the gerber so they can use a router or mill.